# github mielstone cumulative flow rally app

Tags: github, rally, milestone

At our organization we are using this Milestone Cumulative Flow app that was found in Github, but it has some quirks that I am trying to get resolved.

Here's the link to the app: [GitHub - RallyCommunity/MilestoneCumulativeFlow](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/MilestoneCumulativeFlow)

Said quirks are:

- The app is picking up points only if at least one of the stories is "in progress" (which populates the "actual start date" that's being used in the code) (we are working around this by creating a dummy story "in progress")
- The app doesn't pick up points if an epic has stories belonging to a different project and if this project doesn't already have any Epics mapped to the milestone. ( we are working around this by creating a dummy epic in the other project)
- The app doesn't pick up points if Epic is not mapped, and Theme and stories are mapped.
- The app does double counting of points if there are nested user stories. I had this fixed with the help of someone here.

I'm looking for help with fixing the code at least with the first two problems.

Thanks!
Niv

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO is not a code writing service. If you have specific questions, or want help debugging, please provide the relevant snippet of code and the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This app was written prior to there being an in-product version of this chart.  Can you use the built-in milestone cumulative flow chart instead?

Comment: Hi Kyle, Okay, I didn't know that. The custom app has checkboxes for team selection and drop downs for milestone selection that we find really useful and these don't come with the standard app. There's also a straight line comparison of ideal work completion vs actual completion rate.